# The best way to write down my English name

Tags: american-english, word-usage, business-language

I would like to ask for native English speakers’ opinion on the best way to write down my English name.

My name is Minhyuk Lim(Korean name), and in the most of business circumstances, foreign business partners do not know how to pronounce Minhyuk. In fact, my name, just like the most of Korean names, is consist of two syllables (Min + Hyuk) written in two separate letters in Korean. So I normally use just Min as an English name, not using the second syllable ‘Hyuk’.

I have been called as Min and would like to keep being called Min going forward. At the same time, however, I would like to represent my full name in my corporate namecard or the like. What could be the best way to write down my name among examples as below?

> Min (Minhyuk) Lim
>
> Minhyuk (Min) Lim
>
> Min H. Lim
>
> Min Lim

Comment: Minhyuk (Min) Lim.  The convention is that the name in parenthesis is  the name you want to be called.

Comment: Another option is Min Hyuk Lim, but indicating the preferred form for addressing you is useful.

Comment: Out of interest which name is your inherited family name and which is your personal given name? I understand that traditionally Korean family names are normally placed first and are followed by the given name. However Lim looks more like a family name to me. If this is the case I would suggest that you use Min and Hyuk as separate given (forenames), include the H as an initial if you wish and expect people to call you Min. This would follow normal English practice. Think of George W Bush, Franklin D Roosevelt and Darryl F Zanuck.

Comment: Thanks all. I will consider either Min H. Lim or Minhyuk (Min) Lim. Considering I do not have a middle name, technically, Minhyuk (Min) Lim could be more suitable. To BoldBen: yes Lim is a family name and Minhyuk is my personal given name. Min H Lim seems that I have a middle name starting with H. Isn’t it?

Comment: Minhyuk "Min" Lim is also acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

To some extent this is a matter of personal preference. However, in the US at least, it is common on business cards and e-mail to use one of the following options:

- Minhyuk "Min" Lim
- Minhyuk (Min) Lim

The quotes or parenthesis indicate the name you prefer to be addressed by.

You also might consider hyphenating your given name - hyphenation is not an uncommon way for Koreans to transliterate their disyllabic given names into English, making them look a bit easier to pronounce.

- Min-Hyuk "Min" Lim
- Min-Hyuk (Min) Lim

Answer (score 0):

Presumably in Korea your name, in Romanized alphabetical characters would be written ***Lim Min-Hyuk***.

The idea of putting a single middle initial e.g. George W. Bush, is an American style, not nearly so often used in Britain, where we either quote a single first name, or initials only. In your case that would be either ***Min Lim*** or ***M.H.Lim***.

Comment: OP's name is not Minh-Yuk, it's Min-Hyuk.

Comment: Also, Korean characters are alphabetical.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I apologise to you and the OP for the schoolboy error of assuming Koreans used pictographic characters. (Though the Korean "alphabet" is not quite how we consider an alphabet I believe. Some characters relate to syllables. ) I have made the necessary amendments to my post.